# Why does the background image sometime doesn't show on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML which has a background image:

```
<a href="find_provider.aspx" class="tabText" title="F">
    <div id="fp" class="mainImageNav floatLeft fp">
        <img src="theImages/icon.png" class="tabIcon vertAlign" title="F" alt="F" /> Find P
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.tabText {
    color: #FFF;
}
.mainImageNav
{
    width: 25%;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: small;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Arial', 'Verdana';
    font-weight: bold;
}
.fp
{
    background: url('NotActive.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.floatLeft {
    float: left;
}
.tabIcon
{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
.vertAlign {
    vertically-align: middle;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    preload([
    '../theImages/Active.png',
    '../theImages/NotActive.png',
    ]);

    $('#fp').hover(function () {
        $('#fp').css("background-image", "url('Active.png')");
    }, function () {
        $('#fp').css("background-image", "url('NotActive.png')");
    });
});

function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function () {
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}
```

The issue I am having is, when the page first loads, the image is shown but when I hover over for the image to be changed, most of the time the background image becomes white instead showing the changed image and then when I move my mouse away, the background remains white instead going back to the default image.

Please help me resolve it, so that the image changes and goes back to the default state without displaying a white background.

Comment: Why aren't you just using CSS's `:hover` pseudo selector for this?

Comment: I put in the CSS `:hover` and also the JQuery now and when I move my mouse over fast enough it still takes split second for the background to show and shows white for that time.

Comment: Thats because your background image isn;t actually loaded in the first time you do this - you should to using sprites in that case, to load the image before the user hovers. Check this doc on sprites (its W3Schools, but its useful) http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Comment: I am using background-size to fill the entire background so that is causing the issue.

Comment: The background size is important, otherwise there are white spaces in between.

Comment: its not about your size, thats all fine. Background size makes no difference to the load, and a computer is fast enough to do this in an instance.

Comment: I used a sprite and there was some extra white space left over.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your css from using .fp to #fp